# Trouble with hotreload on TypeScript / docker environnement

Tags: typescript, docker-compose, hot-reload

Hello i have build a TypeScript application but I don't have the hot reload i had the same problem with another project were i worked with 3 other people which didn"t had my issue. This project is build with docker compose [My code files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apz25.png). Sorry if my english is not really good and thank you for your time,

Simon

I've already try things that i see in others topics like add FAST_REFRESH=false in my .env
"start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start" add this in my package.json